# Integration testing of EJBs

Tags: spring, integration-testing, junit4

I have a set of EJBs, which persist and retrieve data from a Sybase database through a set of DAO classes.
The DAO classes are POJOs, which execute directly sql procedures(prepared statement) over JDBC datasource.
What would be the appropriate framework to prepare an integration testing suite for these EJBs ,using some meaningful simulated data in the database?
Does spring/junit provide some help?
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think unit testing is enough depending on what you're trying to validate.

If you need to test only the EJB I would go with a mocked version of your DAO that work in-memory (a DAO with a HashMap to save and retrieve data for example) so you can focus your tests on the input and output of your EJB methods. This way you can also populate your test data programmatically.

If you also need to test the Sybase statements generated by your DAO I think you could separate the methods that actually execute the statements from those that generate the SQL, this way you could validate the SQL generated without needing a connection to the database.

If you really need to validate your tests against the database engine you could try to configure a [Profile](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) for your Integration tests with a valid database connection and bind this connection to your DAO bean. You can even populate this database with some testing data via script.